# Modify data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with several columns, for simplication this a reduced version:

```
ID    geo    value
a1    FR    3        
a1    ES    7    
a1    DE    6     
a2    FR    3    
a2    ES    5     
a2    DE    10
```

I want to modify some of the values, my file is huge, based in some conditions.

Ideally I would do:

```
df[(df.ID=='1') & (df.geo=='DE')]['value']=9999
```

But this doesn't work, I guess because I obtaining a copy of my original dataframe instead the dataframe

Any simple way to update values based in complex conditions?

Comment: What you are doing is called [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) so you are right you are operating on a copy in this case, you should use the new indexing methods `ix`, `iloc` and `loc` to avoid this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
condition = (df.ID=='a1') & (df.geo=='DE')
df.ix[condition, 'value'] = 9999
```